# Task.Factory.StartNew with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, parallel-processing

I'm trying to refactor some code to achieve more throughput through parallelism.  I did all the base refactoring to where I had my minimalist single call that would be thread-safe.  My method takes multiple parameters:

```
private Domain ImportDomain(ConstructorInfo domainConstructor,
                            string[] domainAttributes, DateTime importDate)
{
    ...
}
```

I have working code which iterates calls to this method, simply as such:

```
ImportDomain(myConstructor, myAttributes, myDate);
```

All works totally fine before I try adding in parallelism.

I thought I would simply be able to do this:

```
Task<Domain>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    ImportDomain(myConstructor, myAttributes, myDate)
);
```

and add a catch block to handle any AggregateException which might be thrown.

However, what I found was that `ImportDomain()` was never called with this code, although the `StartNew()` line was executing.  I have a feeling this may be due to my relative inexperience with lambda expressions, but I'm also seeing that all examples using `StartNew()` either use delegates, or pass a single param.

What is the simplest solution to making my multi-parameter call compatible with `Task.Factory.StartNew()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you need is to name the task, and get the Result of the completed import.

```
Task<Domain> someDomainTask = Task<Domain>.Factory.StartNew(() => 
  { 
    return ImportDomain(myConstructor, myAttributes, myDate);
  } 
);
Domain someDomain = someDomainTask.Result;
```